# How to avoid including the Today Widget in my App Store build?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-today-widget

I'm creating a Today Widget for my iOS8 app.
However, until it's ready and fully working, I'm wondering how I can exclude it from being compiled/embedded into the builds I give out to testers (or to the build for the AppStore, in case it's not finished in time)

Answer (score 1):

In your project target,try removing widget target-->general from "Embedded binaries".Also disable "App group" in Target-->Capabilities